# Change execution directory

Tags: c#, mutation-testing, stryker, stryker-net

I'm playing around with [stryker.net](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/reporters/) but get a file not found exception, which is not unusual, because I've got some dependencies which are stored in an other directory, where my output files are copied to. How to change the test-directory of stryker? The specific file which it's searching for is one of those dependencies.

```
    Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'some.dll'.
File name: 'some.dll'
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.CreateFile(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.StandardFileSystem.OpenFile(String filePath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Roslyn.Utilities.CommonCompilerFileSystemExtensions.OpenFileWithNormalizedException(ICommonCompilerFileSystem fileSystem, String filePath, FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess, FileShare fileShare)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(String path, MetadataReferenceProperties properties, DocumentationProvider documentation)
   at Stryker.Core.Initialisation.Buildalyzer.IAnalyzerResultExtensions.LoadReferences(IAnalyzerResult analyzerResult)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Stryker.Core/Stryker.Core/Initialisation/Buildalyzer/IAnalyzerResultExtensions.cs:line 98
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray.CreateRange[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ImmutableArrayExtensions.AsImmutableOrEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.ValidateReferences[T](IEnumerable`1 references)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.Create(String assemblyName, CSharpCompilationOptions options, IEnumerable`1 syntaxTrees, IEnumerable`1 references, CSharpCompilation previousSubmission, Type returnType, Type hostObjectType, Boolean isSubmission)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.Create(String assemblyName, IEnumerable`1 syntaxTrees, IEnumerable`1 references, CSharpCompilationOptions options)
   at Stryker.Core.Compiling.CsharpCompilingProcess.GetCSharpCompilation(IEnumerable`1 syntaxTrees) in /_/src/Stryker.Core/Stryker.Core/Compiling/CsharpCompilingProcess.cs:line 138
   at Stryker.Core.Compiling.CsharpCompilingProcess.GetSemanticModels(IEnumerable`1 syntaxTrees) in /_/src/Stryker.Core/Stryker.Core/Compiling/CsharpCompilingProcess.cs:line 102
   at Stryker.Core.MutationTest.CsharpMutationProcess.Mutate(MutationTestInput input) in /_/src/Stryker.Core/Stryker.Core/MutationTest/CsharpMutationProcess.cs:line 59
   at Stryker.Core.MutationTest.MutationTestProcess.Mutate() in /_/src/Stryker.Core/Stryker.Core/MutationTest/MutationTestProcess.cs:line 88
   at Stryker.Core.Initialisation.ProjectMutator.MutateProject(StrykerOptions options, MutationTestInput input, IReporter reporters) in /_/src/Stryker.Core/Stryker.Core/Initialisation/ProjectMutator.cs:line 38
   at Stryker.Core.Initialisation.ProjectOrchestrator.MutateProjects(StrykerOptions options, IReporter reporters, ITestRunner runner)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Stryker.Core/Stryker.Core/Initialisation/ProjectOrchestrator.cs:line 68
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Stryker.Core.StrykerRunner.RunMutationTest(IStrykerInputs inputs, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IProjectOrchestrator projectOrchestrator) in /_/src/Stryker.Core/Stryker.Core/StrykerRunner.cs:line 61
   at Stryker.CLI.StrykerCli.RunStryker(IStrykerInputs inputs) in /_/src/Stryker.CLI/Stryker.CLI/StrykerCLI.cs:line 102
   at Stryker.CLI.StrykerCli.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Run>b__0() in /_/src/Stryker.CLI/Stryker.CLI/StrykerCLI.cs:line 74
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.<>c__DisplayClass143_0.<OnExecute>b__0(CancellationToken _)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at McMaster.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Stryker.CLI.StrykerCli.Run(String[] args) in /_/src/Stryker.CLI/Stryker.CLI/StrykerCLI.cs:line 80
   at Stryker.CLI.Program.Main(String[] args) in /_/src/Stryker.CLI/Stryker.CLI/Program.cs:line 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how you execute Stryker (from the test folder or from the repo root) - but basically you can do 2 things:

- configure the name of the target project using [--project](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/configuration/#project-file-name)
- configure the path to the test project using [--test-project](https://stryker-mutator.io/docs/stryker-net/configuration/#test-projects-string)